# Woocommerce Product variations not saving

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Am using woocommerce I justover write one function using hook because I need to calculate the price of each product using a formula so what I did is I just copy the original function modified it and add it in my function.php and I see it is working fine in my local machine but not in my server. In server it is not saving the variations.

Here I add the code that I added in my finctions.php

```
    remove_action('woocommerce_product_write_panels', 'variable_product_type_options');

    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_write_panels','variable_product_type_options_with_goldprice_calculation' );

    function variable_product_type_options_with_goldprice_calculation(){

    global $post, $woocommerce;

    $attributes = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_product_attributes', true ) );

    // See if any are set
    $variation_attribute_found = false;
    if ( $attributes ) foreach( $attributes as $attribute ) {
    if ( isset( $attribute['is_variation'] ) ) {
$variation_attribute_found = true;
break;
}
}

// Get tax classes
$tax_classes = array_filter( array_map('trim', explode( "\n", get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_classes' ) ) ) );
$tax_class_options = array();
$tax_class_options['parent'] = __( 'Same as parent', 'woocommerce' );
$tax_class_options[''] = __( 'Standard', 'woocommerce' );
if ( $tax_classes )
foreach ( $tax_classes as $class )
$tax_class_options[ sanitize_title( $class ) ] = esc_attr( $class );
?>
<div id="variable_product_options" class="panel wc-metaboxes-wrapper"><div id="variable_product_options_inner">

<?php if ( ! $variation_attribute_found ) : ?>

<div id="message" class="inline woocommerce-message">
<div class="squeezer">
<h4><?php _e( 'Before adding variations, add and save some attributes on the <strong>Attributes</strong> tab.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h4>

<p class="submit"><a class="button-primary" href="http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-variations/" target="_blank"><?php _e( 'Learn more', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a></p>
</div>
</div>

<?php else : ?>

<p class="toolbar">
<a href="#" class="close_all"><?php _e( 'Close all', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a><a href="#" class="expand_all"><?php _e( 'Expand all', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
<strong><?php _e( 'Bulk edit:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></strong>
<select id="field_to_edit">
<option value="toggle_enabled"><?php _e( 'Toggle &quot;Enabled&quot;', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
<option value="toggle_downloadable"><?php _e( 'Toggle &quot;Downloadable&quot;', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
<option value="toggle_virtual"><?php _e( 'Toggle &quot;Virtual&quot;', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
<option value="delete_all"><?php _e( 'Delete all variations', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
<option value="variable_regular_price"><?php _e( 'Prices', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
<option value="variable_sale_price"><?php _e( 'Sale prices', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
<option value="variable_stock"><?php _e( 'Stock', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
<option value="variable_weight"><?php _e( 'Weight', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
<option value="variable_length"><?php _e( 'Length', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
<option value="variable_width"><?php _e( 'Width', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
<option value="variable_height"><?php _e( 'Height', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
<option value="variable_file_paths" rel="textarea"><?php _e( 'File Path', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
<option value="variable_download_limit"><?php _e( 'Download limit', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
<option value="variable_download_expiry"><?php _e( 'Download Expiry', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_variable_product_bulk_edit_actions' ); ?>
</select>
<a class="button bulk_edit"><?php _e( 'Go', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
</p>

<div class="woocommerce_variations wc-metaboxes">
<?php
// Get parent data
$parent_data = array(
'id' => $post->ID,
'attributes' => $attributes,
'tax_class_options' => $tax_class_options,
'sku' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_sku', true ),
'weight' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_weight', true ),
'length' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_length', true ),
'width' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_width', true ),
'height' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_height', true ),
'tax_class' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_tax_class', true )
);

if ( ! $parent_data['weight'] )
$parent_data['weight'] = '0.00';

if ( ! $parent_data['length'] )
$parent_data['length'] = '0';

if ( ! $parent_data['width'] )
$parent_data['width'] = '0';

if ( ! $parent_data['height'] )
$parent_data['height'] = '0';

// Get variations
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product_variation',
'post_status' => array( 'private', 'publish' ),
'numberposts' => -1,
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'order' => 'asc',
'post_parent' => $post->ID
);
$variations = get_posts( $args );
$loop = 0;
if ( $variations ) foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {

$variation_id = absint( $variation->ID );
$variation_post_status = esc_attr( $variation->post_status );
$variation_data = get_post_meta( $variation_id );
$variation_data['variation_post_id'] = $variation_id;

// Grab shipping classes
$shipping_classes = get_the_terms( $variation_id, 'product_shipping_class' );
$shipping_class = ( $shipping_classes && ! is_wp_error( $shipping_classes ) ) ? current( $shipping_classes )->term_id : '';

$variation_fields = array(
'_sku',
'_stock',
'_price',
'_regular_price',
'_sale_price',
'_weight',
'_length',
'_width',
'_height',
'_tax_class',
'_download_limit',
'_download_expiry',
'_file_paths',
'_downloadable',
'_virtual',
'_thumbnail_id',
'_sale_price_dates_from',
'_sale_price_dates_to'
);

foreach ( $variation_fields as $field )
$$field = isset( $variation_data[ $field ][0] ) ? $variation_data[ $field ][0] : '';

// Price backwards compat
if ( $_regular_price == '' && $_price ){
$_regular_price = $_price;
}
/*External Added
* @Author : Sanjay

* To set the variable price from the formula
*/
else{
if(isset($variation_data['attribute_pa_materiaal'][0]) && ($variation_data['attribute_pa_materiaal'][0] != 'zilver-2' && $variation_data['attribute_pa_materiaal'][0] != 'zilver')){

$ringthickness = explode('-',$variation_data[ 'attribute_pa_dikte-van-de-ring' ][0]);
if($thickness[0] !=0){
$ringthickness = $thickness[0];
}
else{
$ringthickness = 1;
}
if($variation_data[ 'attribute_pa_breedte' ][0] != ''){
$ringwidth = $variation_data[ 'attribute_pa_breedte' ][0];
}
else{
$ringwidth = 1;
}
if($variation_data[ 'attribute_pa_ringmaat' ][0] != ''){
$ringsize = $variation_data[ 'attribute_pa_ringmaat' ][0];
}
elseif($variation_data[ 'attribute_ringmaat' ][0] != ''){
$ringsize = $variation_data[ 'attribute_ringmaat' ][0];
}
else{
$ringsize = 1;
}
if($variation_data[ 'attribute_pa_vast-prijsdeel' ][0] != ''){
$labour_price = $variation_data[ 'attribute_pa_vast-prijsdeel' ][0] ;
}
if($variation_data[ 'attribute_pa_prijsdeel-per-mm2' ][0] != ''){
$gold_price = str_replace('-','',$variation_data[ 'attribute_pa_prijsdeel-per-mm2' ][0] );
}
$_regular_price = ($ringsize*3.14*$ringwidth*$ringthickness)+$labour_price+$gold_price;

}
}
/*Here Ends*/

// Get image
$image = '';
$image_id = absint( $_thumbnail_id );
if ( $image_id )
$image = wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id );

// Format file paths
$_file_paths = maybe_unserialize( $_file_paths );
if ( is_array( $_file_paths ) )
$_file_paths = implode( "\n", $_file_paths );

include( ABSPATH.'wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/admin/post-types/writepanels/variation-admin-html.php' );

$loop++;
}
?>
</div>

<p class="toolbar">

<button type="button" class="button button-primary add_variation" <?php disabled( $variation_attribute_found, false ); ?>><?php _e( 'Add Variation', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>

<button type="button" class="button link_all_variations" <?php disabled( $variation_attribute_found, false ); ?>><?php _e( 'Link all variations', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>

<strong><?php _e( 'Default selections:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></strong>
<?php
$default_attributes = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_default_attributes', true ) );
foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

// Only deal with attributes that are variations
if ( ! $attribute['is_variation'] )
continue;

// Get current value for variation (if set)
$variation_selected_value = isset( $default_attributes[ sanitize_title( $attribute['name'] ) ] ) ? $default_attributes[ sanitize_title( $attribute['name'] ) ] : '';

// Name will be something like attribute_pa_color
echo '<select name="default_attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute['name'] ) . '"><option value="">' . __( 'No default', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ' . esc_html( $woocommerce->attribute_label( $attribute['name'] ) ) . '&hellip;</option>';

// Get terms for attribute taxonomy or value if its a custom attribute
if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] ) {

$post_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $attribute['name'] );

foreach ( $post_terms as $term )
echo '<option ' . selected( $variation_selected_value, $term->slug, false ) . ' value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', esc_html( $term->name ) ) . '</option>';

} else {

$options = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|', $attribute['value'] ) );

foreach ( $options as $option )
echo '<option ' . selected( sanitize_title( $variation_selected_value ), sanitize_title( $option ), false ) . ' value="' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $option ) ) . '">' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) ) . '</option>';

}

echo '</select>';
}
?>
</p>

<?php endif; ?>
</div></div>
<?php
/**
* Product Type Javascript
*/
ob_start();
?>
jQuery(function(){

var variation_sortable_options = {
items:'.woocommerce_variation',
cursor:'move',
axis:'y',
handle: 'h3',
scrollSensitivity:40,
forcePlaceholderSize: true,
helper: 'clone',
opacity: 0.65,
placeholder: 'wc-metabox-sortable-placeholder',
start:function(event,ui){
ui.item.css('background-color','#f6f6f6');
},
stop:function(event,ui){
ui.item.removeAttr('style');
variation_row_indexes();
}
};

// Add a variation
jQuery('#variable_product_options').on('click', 'button.add_variation', function(){

jQuery('.woocommerce_variations').block({ message: null, overlayCSS: { background: '#fff url(<?php echo $woocommerce->plugin_url(); ?>/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center', opacity: 0.6 } });

var loop = jQuery('.woocommerce_variation').size();

var data = {
action: 'woocommerce_add_variation',
post_id: <?php echo $post->ID; ?>,
loop: loop,
security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("add-variation"); ?>'
};

jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function(response) {

jQuery('.woocommerce_variations').append( response );

jQuery(".tips").tipTip({
'attribute' : 'data-tip',
'fadeIn' : 50,
'fadeOut' : 50
});

jQuery('input.variable_is_downloadable, input.variable_is_virtual').change();

jQuery('.woocommerce_variations').unblock();
jQuery('#variable_product_options').trigger('woocommerce_variations_added');
});

return false;

});

jQuery('#variable_product_options').on('click', 'button.link_all_variations', function(){

var answer = confirm('<?php _e( 'Are you sure you want to link all variations? This will create a new variation for each and every possible combination of variation attributes (max 50 per run).', 'woocommerce' ); ?>');

if (answer) {

jQuery('#variable_product_options').block({ message: null, overlayCSS: { background: '#fff url(<?php echo $woocommerce->plugin_url(); ?>/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center', opacity: 0.6 } });

var data = {
action: 'woocommerce_link_all_variations',
post_id: <?php echo $post->ID; ?>,
security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("link-variations"); ?>'
};

jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function(response) {

var count = parseInt( response );

if (count==1) {
alert( count + ' <?php _e( "variation added", 'woocommerce' ); ?>');
} else if (count==0 || count>1) {
alert( count + ' <?php _e( "variations added", 'woocommerce' ); ?>');
} else {
alert('<?php _e( "No variations added", 'woocommerce' ); ?>');
}

if (count>0) {
var this_page = window.location.toString();

this_page = this_page.replace( 'post-new.php?', 'post.php?post=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>&action=edit&' );

$('#variable_product_options').load( this_page + ' #variable_product_options_inner', function() {
$('#variable_product_options').unblock();
jQuery('#variable_product_options').trigger('woocommerce_variations_added');
} );
} else {
$('#variable_product_options').unblock();
}

});
}
return false;
});

jQuery('#variable_product_options').on('click', 'button.remove_variation', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var answer = confirm('<?php _e( 'Are you sure you want to remove this variation?', 'woocommerce' ); ?>');
if (answer){

var el = jQuery(this).parent().parent();

var variation = jQuery(this).attr('rel');

if (variation>0) {

jQuery(el).block({ message: null, overlayCSS: { background: '#fff url(<?php echo $woocommerce->plugin_url(); ?>/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center', opacity: 0.6 } });

var data = {
action: 'woocommerce_remove_variation',
variation_id: variation,
security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("delete-variation"); ?>'
};

jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function(response) {
// Success
jQuery(el).fadeOut('300', function(){
jQuery(el).remove();
});
});

} else {
jQuery(el).fadeOut('300', function(){
jQuery(el).remove();
});
}

}
return false;
});

jQuery('.wc-metaboxes-wrapper').on('click', 'a.bulk_edit', function(event){
var field_to_edit = jQuery('select#field_to_edit').val();

if ( field_to_edit == 'toggle_enabled' ) {
var checkbox = jQuery('input[name^="variable_enabled"]');
checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked'));
return false;
}
else if ( field_to_edit == 'toggle_downloadable' ) {
var checkbox = jQuery('input[name^="variable_is_downloadable"]');
checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked'));
jQuery('input.variable_is_downloadable').change();
return false;
}
else if ( field_to_edit == 'toggle_virtual' ) {
var checkbox = jQuery('input[name^="variable_is_virtual"]');
checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked'));
jQuery('input.variable_is_virtual').change();
return false;
}
else if ( field_to_edit == 'delete_all' ) {

var answer = confirm('<?php _e( 'Are you sure you want to delete all variations? This cannot be undone.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>');
if (answer){

var answer = confirm('<?php _e( 'Last warning, are you sure?', 'woocommerce' ); ?>');

if (answer) {

var variation_ids = [];

jQuery('.woocommerce_variations .woocommerce_variation').block({ message: null, overlayCSS: { background: '#fff url(<?php echo $woocommerce->plugin_url(); ?>/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center', opacity: 0.6 } });

jQuery('.woocommerce_variations .woocommerce_variation .remove_variation').each(function(){

var variation = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
if (variation>0) {
variation_ids.push(variation);
}
});

var data = {
action: 'woocommerce_remove_variations',
variation_ids: variation_ids,
security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("delete-variations"); ?>'
};

jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function(response) {
jQuery('.woocommerce_variations .woocommerce_variation').fadeOut('300', function(){
jQuery('.woocommerce_variations .woocommerce_variation').remove();
});
});

}

}
return false;
}
else {

var input_tag = jQuery('select#field_to_edit :selected').attr('rel') ? jQuery('select#field_to_edit :selected').attr('rel') : 'input';

var value = prompt("<?php _e( 'Enter a value', 'woocommerce' ); ?>");
jQuery(input_tag + '[name^="' + field_to_edit + '["]').val( value ).change();
return false;

}
});

jQuery('#variable_product_options').on('change', 'input.variable_is_downloadable', function(){

jQuery(this).closest('.woocommerce_variation').find('.show_if_variation_downloadable').hide();

if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
jQuery(this).closest('.woocommerce_variation').find('.show_if_variation_downloadable').show();
}

});

jQuery('#variable_product_options').on('change', 'input.variable_is_virtual', function(){

jQuery(this).closest('.woocommerce_variation').find('.hide_if_variation_virtual').show();

if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
jQuery(this).closest('.woocommerce_variation').find('.hide_if_variation_virtual').hide();
}

});

jQuery('input.variable_is_downloadable, input.variable_is_virtual').change();

// Ordering
$('#variable_product_options').on( 'woocommerce_variations_added', function() {
$('.woocommerce_variations').sortable( variation_sortable_options );
} );

$('.woocommerce_variations').sortable( variation_sortable_options );

function variation_row_indexes() {
$('.woocommerce_variations .woocommerce_variation').each(function(index, el){
$('.variation_menu_order', el).val( parseInt( $(el).index('.woocommerce_variations .woocommerce_variation') ) );
});
};

// Uploader
var variable_image_frame;
var setting_variation_image_id;
var setting_variation_image;
var wp_media_post_id = wp.media.model.settings.post.id;

jQuery('#variable_product_options').on('click', '.upload_image_button', function( event ) {

var $button = jQuery( this );
var post_id = $button.attr('rel');
var $parent = $button.closest('.upload_image');
setting_variation_image = $parent;
setting_variation_image_id = post_id;

event.preventDefault();

if ( $button.is('.remove') ) {

setting_variation_image.find( '.upload_image_id' ).val( '' );
setting_variation_image.find( 'img' ).attr( 'src', '<?php echo woocommerce_placeholder_img_src(); ?>' );
setting_variation_image.find( '.upload_image_button' ).removeClass( 'remove' );

} else {

// If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
if ( variable_image_frame ) {
variable_image_frame.uploader.uploader.param( 'post_id', setting_variation_image_id );
variable_image_frame.open();
return;
} else {
wp.media.model.settings.post.id = setting_variation_image_id;
}

// Create the media frame.
variable_image_frame = wp.media.frames.variable_image = wp.media({
// Set the title of the modal.
title: '<?php _e( 'Choose an image', 'woocommerce' ); ?>',
button: {
text: '<?php _e( 'Set variation image', 'woocommerce' ); ?>'
}
});

// When an image is selected, run a callback.
variable_image_frame.on( 'select', function() {

attachment = variable_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

setting_variation_image.find( '.upload_image_id' ).val( attachment.id );
setting_variation_image.find( '.upload_image_button' ).addClass( 'remove' );
setting_variation_image.find( 'img' ).attr( 'src', attachment.url );

wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;
});

// Finally, open the modal.
variable_image_frame.open();
}
});

// Restore ID
jQuery('a.add_media').on('click', function() {
wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;
} );

});
<?php
$javascript = ob_get_clean();
$woocommerce->add_inline_js( $javascript );

}
```

variable_product_type_options : this is the original function so I removed that and added variable_product_type_options_with_goldprice_calculation but it is not saving the values in server. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance using WooCommerce version 2.0.11?

There's a bug with product variations in the backend in that version. It's fixed in the latest version (2.0.12) so update WooCommerce and check again.

See more about it here(Needs a WooThemes account to read unfortunately): http://support.woothemes.com/entries/24127722-Woocommerce-2-0-11-BUGGY

Comment: But when am using the original function of woocommerce it works fine for me it is having issue when am trying with my custom function(as this function is exact copy of original one with a few line of code additional) it is not working